# Comparison of CA Software Change Manager (Harvest) and Git according to Revision Control

Tags: git, version-control, revision, harvest-scm

I've just worked with Git until now, but a few days ago I was confronted with CA Software Change Manager (Harvest). I was searching for small tutorials for Harvest but I haven't found anything suitable.
I'd be pleased if anyone who is experienced (or has knowledge about it) with both, Git and Harvest, could tell me whats the difference according to the workflow.

E.g.: in Git a developer creates branches from the master branch for getting his personal working copy, commits and pushes his changes in the sub-branch, pulls the latest changes from the master before going to merge the sub-branch with the master branch, ect.

How is this done with Harvest or whats the general workflow?

Thx a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Parallel work can be done in CA Harvest SCM too. The understanding you have gained is a little bit flawed. A "change package" is atomic unit in the lifecycle. It is a group of files which are part of a logical change. These packages are owned/assigned to a user and he can work independently.

Now coming to your question, how parallel work is achieved in CA Harvest SCM. This can be done in following way:

Suppose two developers, want to work on same project and expect to change code in same files. Both will create their own respective packages and checkout code. Both will have a separate branch for them. They make their changes and then they promote their package from one state to another(say Dev to Build). This is where they have to merge conflicts if it arises in same file. This merging of conflicts can be done using harvest itself, or harvest also supports integration with 3rd party tools like winmerge etc. So in this way both developers will have their work merged and can take it forward.

Hope it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I've done some investigations and annoyed some colleagues. I've come to the following conclusion:

While creating a working copy of the whole project in Git, in CA SCM there are just so called "Changes Packages" created, which consists of several files. Those files are locked to other developers (for avoiding merge conflicts?)- so there is no parallel work possible. If the modifications in a Change Package is done, then this package has to pass through several stages (e.g.: testing up to production)- so the modifications have to be approved by some dedicated users.

So, is this correct that there is no parallel work possible with CA SCM, because of the locking and that there won't exist a rapid feedback of the changes (because the developer has to wait for the approval of some colleagues)?

What do you think?

Comment: I am looking at the same issue now: how CA-SCM can support parallel development like git. There is a "sibling project" in CA-SCM may be able to used as a branch.

Answer (score 0):

Parallel development is possible.
You have to make sure that you checkout from trunk and not branch. When you try to checkout a file it shows you a latest version of the file. This might be a branch checked-out earlier by your colleagues. You have to ensure you checkout the trunk version from which this branch was created.